# What are the different causes for error code 0x3?

Tags: windows, error-handling

It's been a couple times now I end up with programs crashing with a return value of 3. Although I've always managed to solve it by re-writing or changing my code, I am now getting curious for the causes of this error code(And Google doesn't seem to have nearly as much data on it as 0xc0000005). According to [the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-), it happens when *the system cannot find the path specified*.

Now, I might just be bad at understanding english, but I cannot understand how this error can possibly relate to my codes(No files/pointers involved or manipulated in these specific cases). My only guess is the problem being related to some internal DLLs missing.

Could anybody please provide me with further explanation over this error code? I feel like I should understand what is the cause of a problem before trying to even solve it, and it might help in future cases.

Thank you very much.

Comment: That's basically it, there are some files that are missing of corrupt, most likely one or more DLL's. You can use a tool such as [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) to list an executable programs DLL's (and all DLL's dependencies as well). It will tell you if there's some missing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Fortunately smashing the undo button of my IDE allowed me to recompile a crashing version of my last program. I ran Dependency Walker on it, and wow, I saw a lot of red. It seems a huge amounts required dependecies were not found. Most missing DLLs were starting with the API-MS-WIN- suffix(Ex: "API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPCOMPAT-L1-1-0.DLL"). Is there any way fixing this? Is this a common issue?

Comment: this is not a C-tag issue.